# String with CCArray

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I want to store the string in array values with specified position.

For example:

The letter "A" is stored in 3rd position in an array(CCArray).  No values in other position.

I am trying the following code

```
 world->insertObject(character,2);    //character is CCString
```

The above method is pushed the existing values to next place. I want to over write the existing one.

The new character is stored in second place.  There is no need old value.

Can any one assist me?

Comment: So what's wrong with deleteObject then insertObject?

Comment: @start: Thanks a lot.  It works fine.  word->removeObjectAtIndex(4);word->insertObject(character,4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above logic have the following coding

```
word->removeObjectAtIndex(4);
word->insertObject(character,4);
```

First remove the string and then insert the CCString.

Now it works fine.